# Running a bash script as a less privileged user with upstart

Tags: users, upstart

This is the script, `/home/jack/myscript.sh`, which I want to run:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/
/home/jack/myapp/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/./catalina.sh run
```

The upstart file, `/etc/init/myapp.conf`, that I have written:

```
  description "Myapp Server"
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [06]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5
  exec `su jack -c /home/jack/myscript.sh`
```

So, if I want to run the script as user `jack`, would my above configuration work? Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user), a built-in feature to run a service as a different user is planned but not implemented yet.

If you have `start-stop-daemon`, use it.

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -u jack --exec /home/jack/myscript.sh
```

Otherwise, use `su` (as you did) or `sudo`. Note that `start-stop-daemon` always switches to the indicated user (barring errors), whereas `su` and `sudo` obey their own policy (in particular, the PAM policies on most systems).

Note that in your case, you don't need the intermediate script. You can set environment variables directly from the Upstart service definition.

```
description "Myapp Server"
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [06]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5
  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/
  exec /home/jack/myapp/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Comment: How do I set environment with `start-stop-daemon` and will I be able to write log to a file with it?

Comment: This is an old answer. The `setuid` and `setgid` are already available

Answer (score 4):

As of Upstart 1.4, Upstart has the ability to run a System Job as a specified user using the `setuid` and `setgid` stanzas, e.g:

```
setuid username
setgid groupname
```

On previous versions we can use [User Jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job), which are stored in the user home folder.

Or use some application in the exec command.

If `start-stop-daemon` is available:

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c myuser --exec command
```

With `sudo`:

```
exec sudo -u myuser command
```

With `su`:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' myuser -- command [parameters...]
```

More information [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user)

Comment: Try to summarize the content of links in addition to posting them.  This way your post remains useful even if the external link goes down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as session user just create a [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) (as of 1.7) instead of a system job. Such jobs are not as restrictive as system jobs when it comes to environment variables and are executed as the session's user.